# HTTPRequest: setEntity doesn't work

Tags: android, httprequest

In my android app I'm trying to get (in an asyntask) a json-String from my server through a post-request:

```
        ...

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);


        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getApplicationContext());
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie("www.myExample.com");

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("www.myExample.com/api/");

        post.setHeader("Referer", "https://www.myExample.com/");
        post.setHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        post.setHeader("Cookie", cookies);

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("csrftoken=(.*?);");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cookies);
        String csrftoken = "";
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            csrftoken = matcher.group(1);
        }

        post.setHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);

        >> List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("output_format", "json"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("plain", "true"));


        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8")); <<

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

            String result, line = reader.readLine();
            result = line;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }

            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("result", "not");
            Log.d("result", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ...
```

It seems that the configuration of the entity fails in my case, I always get back the result as if I would have send the request without the Entity with his important nameValuePairs.
I've marked the relevant lines with >> <<.

Answer (score 2):

Update your code as this snippet to post

```
   public String doInBackground(....){  

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String jsonString = "{\"example\": \"go\"}";
            String url = "www.myExample.com/api/";
            HttpPost    httpReq = new HttpPost(url );
            httpReq.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpReq.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonString, "UTF-8");
            httpReq.setEntity(se);
            Log.e("Invoking Post API", ((HttpPost) httpReq).getURI().toString());

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(((HttpPost) httpReq));
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            return result;
    }
```

and this snippet to Get

public String doInBackground(....){

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpReq = new HttpGet("www.myExample.com/api/");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpReq);
    String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    result = responseText;
        return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and on
`String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`
it dies with the following error
`org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: Chunked stream ended unexpectedly`
So I didn't even get a response from the server

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    JSONObject jObjectData = new JSONObject();

    // Create Json Object Data
    jObjectData.put("output_format", "json");
    jObjectData.put("plain", "true");

    request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(jObjectData.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
```